# RC low pass filter PCB layout limitation

Tags: pcb, filter, layout, low-pass, debounce

I have an RC low pass filter for debouncing a GPIO pin. Do I have to place the resistor and the capacitor close to each other?

Currently the capacitor is near the GPIO pin, and the resistor can be found a **few centimeters** away near the TACT button.

Could this PCB layout cause any problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For debouncing a switch, no problem. Putting the two components close together makes debugging a bit easier, but as long as you've got a ground plane the transient current levels are low enough that you shouldn't have any problems.